# How to list all blob image files in ionic-running localhost?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, camera, blob, capacitor

I’m working on my first project of Ionic-Angular.
After I call:

```
const capturedPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
      source: CameraSource.Camera,
      quality: 100
 });
```

I see that a new blob image is created with URL like: `blob:http://localhost:8100/82300d7b-c5b8-4bca-8779-c6b140046e73`
I want to know how many blob images have I created. How can I list all of those images ?
Thank you!

Comment: From these few lines of code and from what you have written it seems that you are using the Ionic Native Camera plugin and running the command: "ionic serve" which opens your app on the browser to view it on localhost: 8100.

However, Ionic Native plugins only work in iOS or Android or PWA compiled apps depending on the plugin.

But you will never be able to use a plugin (cordova or capacitor) on the browser.

In the plug-in documentation, "Browser" refers to a PWA.

So are u running on Android, iOS or what?

Comment: No images are saved since you're not saving them.

Comment: @NiccolòBiagi: Thank you for answering. I am running on browser (localhost) 8100 and Android, followed the instruction here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app. I can run the native camera plugin without problems. The issue is: On my first run, I took 2 photos from Camera and can show them. On my second run, I took 3 photos from Camera and can show them. But now what I want is to show all those 5 photos. I know if from beginning, I added those captured photos to an image array and put to local storage I can achieve that. But I did not. So now how can I show those 5 photos?

Answer (score 0):

you have to push all of your previously added images in array and show in html using for loop to display all images and one more thing add timestamp to it so you identify when image is selected here is demo

```
var images = [];
const capturedPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
      source: CameraSource.Camera,
      quality: 100
 });
images.push(capturedPhoto)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The problem is: When I first ran my application, I took 2 photos and did not add those to the images array. If now (from the 2nd run on) I add new created images to an array, I can only show the new captured images. What I want is to show also the 2 images taken from the 1st run. Do you know how to achieve that ?

Comment: add previous image in local storage and when you run second time then simply retrieve from storage to achieve this